# Do I really need to include string.h?

Tags: c, string, include

I've been teaching myself C programming from some online courses. In there, they said that string specific functions are included in `string.h`  library and I should add an `#include <string.h>` statement to use them.

However, this short program works fine on Windows, using MS Visual Studio Express 2013:

```
char s1[] = "foo ";
char s2[] = "bar";

int main(void) {

    char foo_bar[100];
    strcpy(foo_bar, strcat(s1, s2));

    printf("%s \n", garra_crema);
    return 0; 
}
```

No include directive at all. I also tried other IDE's an it works fine too. So, is it really needed to include string.h for string manipulation? When the include directive is required and when is optional?

Comment: there is not enough space to store the result of combining the string `s1`.

Comment: Does it _bother_ you to include `<string.h>`?

Comment: @MOehm not at all. I'm just trying to understand how things works